# How can I save PendingIntent as an object into Realm, from notificationserviceListener?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, notificationservices

Using `NotificationServiceLister`, I retrieve the `pendingIntent` of notification. Now I want to store that `pendingIntent` as an object, into any offline database like, `realm, greendao, sqlite, ormLite, active android` etc. Is that possible?? If that possible, then, how??? Or is there any alternative way to find the `pendingIntent` of any particular notification???

Comment: I think.. you should give the whole use case (with screenshots) for which you want to get a solution and saving pendingIntent is not the problem that will provide you the solution.

Comment: got solution brother?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the `pendingIntent` object. You can store the unique notification id into database. And on click of `Notification` activity would get launch in which you can extract the `notification id` and see which Notification was clicked by comparing it with your local db.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can I find the pendingIntent from notification id?? it would be so helpful to me :)

Comment: Could you please tell me how exactly you are going to use pendingIntent ? Any use case?

Comment: I want to save statusBarNotification stuffs like, title, message, ticker, icon, pendingIntent in offline database. Then, show it in a list. And then, when user tap on the each item, I want to sent him/her, to the pendingIntent, which i saved in offline database for every notification.

Comment: on list click you want to send `pendingIntent` ?

Comment: Using recycleView, I want to sent users to the pendingIntent :)

Comment: So you are the one who is creating the `pendingIntent` then why not to save it's data before creating a `notification`.

Comment: But the problem is, I am not creating the pendingIntent. I just retrieve the pendingintent of all notification which come to phone by notificationServicelistener.